# How to open a search dialog using an OWL component?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to open a search dialog similar to what happens when you click on "Search More..." on a Many2one field widget using OWL. I understand this has to be done with Javascript.

Here's the component I have written:

```
odoo.define("somari.ImportFromTemplate", function (require) {

    const { Component } = owl;

    const FormRenderer = require("web.FormRenderer");
    const { ComponentWrapper } = require("web.OwlCompatibility");
    var Dialog = require('web.view_dialogs');

    class ImportFromTemplate extends Component {
        static template = "somari.ImportFromTemplate";

        clicked(event){
            var diag = new Dialog.SelectCreateDialog(this, {
                res_model: 'somari.template',
                title: "Select template"
            });
            diag.open();
        }
     };

     FormRenderer.include({
         async _render() {
             await this._super(...arguments);
             for(const element of this.el.querySelectorAll(".somari_import_from_template")) {
                 (new ComponentWrapper(this, ImportFromTemplate))
                     .mount(element)
             }
         }
     });

 });
```

There's an error on the instruction *diag.open()*:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parent._trigger_up is not a function
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. Any clue what's wrong here or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is  *OWL* ?

Comment: Odoo Web Library: https://odoo.github.io/owl/

Comment: Main OWL user is the Odoo ERP, talking with PostgreSQL  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/frontend/owl_components.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `ImportFromTemplate` is an OWL Component and you are instantiating a legacy Odoo Widget `SelectCreateDialog` from `web.view_dialogs`.

You have two options:

1. Rather instantiate a OWL Component dialog. This way you do not need any OWL Compatibility classes. [Example here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/web/static/src/views/calendar/filter_panel/calendar_filter_panel.js#L107-L116).
2. Use a standaloneAdapter from `web.OwlCompatibility` as it will add various compatibility methods - one of those being `_trigger_up`. [Example here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/public/public_root.js#L410-L411).